# Kusto query loop over json array

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I want to loop over a JSON array like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "count" : 30
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "count" : 10
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "count" : 5
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "count" : 15
  }
]
```

So I would like to have a query to project a TotalCount which would basically go over the json array and sum all the count values(30+10+5+15) and display as a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mv-apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) to do so.

For example:

```
datatable(d: dynamic) [
    dynamic([
    {
        "id": 1,
        "count": 30
        },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "count": 10
        },
        {
        "id": 3,
        "count": 5
        },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "count": 15
        }
    ]),
    dynamic([
        {
        "id": 1,
        "count": 3
        },
        {
        "id": 2,
        "count": 1
        },
        {
        "id": 3,
        "count": 50
        },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "count": 1
        }
    ]),
]
| mv-apply d on (
    summarize result = sum(tolong(d['count']))
)
```

| result |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 55 |

Comment: Thanks @Yoni L. for the quick reply. Do I have to first use todynamic(json_name) ?

Comment: only if the source column is of type `string`. otherwise, if it's already of type `dynamic`, that's not required.